# Virtualbox guest(winXP32bit) registry value reset on every boot

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, windows-registry, virtual-desktop

I have software installed on my guest system which won't run when it detects it is running on virtual os.

I need to change the following registry entries in the guest.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/DESCRIPTION/System/SystemBiosVersion 
from VBOX -1 to NOBOX -1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/ACPI/DSDT/VBOX_
rename this to
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/ACPI/DSDT/NOBOX_

after i made these changes the program runs but on every single reboot these values reset.

I would like to make these entries permanent.

Comment: Does it need a security dongle (stuff that more or less died with XP)

Comment: Its possible those keys and values have permissions that do not allow saving changes across a reboot or when the program is executed they may also revert.>>>>>>>>>>>https://windowsreport.com/regedit-doesnt-save-changes/

Answer (score 0):

As you are on VirtualBox, you don't need to reboot the VM.
You can either put the guest to sleep, or suspend the VM, or take a snapshot of it after
doing your fixes. This is the simplest solution and does not require one of the
techniques described below.

Another simple solution is to create a script that does the registry changes
and set it to run on boot as a Startup script via Group Policy (gpedit.msc)
in *Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)*.

If you find that the registry changes that you described are not enough,
the problem is that there are many ways for the guest to detect that it is running
inside a VM. See the article
[Anti-Virtualization Malware](https://www.deepinstinct.com/2019/10/29/malware-evasion-techniques-part-2-anti-vm-blog/)
for the many techniques for detecting VirtualBox, starting with the registry and
ending with the unstoppable CPUID hardware instruction.

You might be able to find help in the article
[Making Virtualbox nearly undetectable](http://blog.michaelboman.org/2014/01/making-virtualbox-nearly-undetectable.html),
where a Python program is shown that modifies the BIOS of the VM with elements
from the host BIOS to trick Windows so it doesn't detect it is running
inside a VM.